# настройка OpenVPN сервера и клиента, вменяемый мануал

Tags: centos, openvpn

ни разу ни админ
клиент к примеру версии 3.3.6
не нашел как из ключей и сертификатов сгенерить профиль для клиента *.ovpn включающий все необходимые ключи и сертификаты
какая то инструкция есть для этого от конца 2022 года или за этот год
в нескольких местах описывается генерация ключей и затем копирование их с сервера на к примеру десктоп в каталог пользователя

мне же нужно утилиту или последовательность действий, чтобы сгенерить профиль .ovpn включающий все хозяйство.
пытался руками собрать в кучу, клиент бесконечно соединяется и все

Answer (score 0):

https://serveradmin.ru/ustanovka-openvpn-na-vds-server/
это все что нужно для того чтобы по дефолту поставить OpenVPN